# How to convert floating point numbers in fortran format to decimals using shell (bash) tools?

Tags: bash

How to most easily convert floating point numbers to decimals using shell (bash) tools? 
For example: I have `0.17879D-13` as input and want `0.000000000000017879` as output. I have tried `awk` and `bc` but couldn't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Now I got something. I use sed to replace "D" by "e" then awk can process it, eg:

echo 0.17879D-13 | sed s/D/e/g  | awk '{printf("%.20f\n",$1)}'

Comment: As per your required output mentioned in the question you should use `echo 0.17879D-13 | sed s/D/e/g | awk '{printf("%.18f\n",$1)}'`